# How to display table data more clearly in oracle sqlplus

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

I want to be able to display the resulting data from a select in a pretty way, not all columns under others.

Here is the way sqlplus displays my table data:

[image]

But I want to show them as:

```
Name   |    Address    |    Phone    |
-------+---------------+-------------+
name1  |    address1   |    phone1   |
name2  |    address2   |    phone2   |
name3  |    address3   |    phone3   |
```

Not each column under the other

Comment: errr.. i want to show them just like a normal table. one after another one

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I usually start with something like:

```
set lines 256
set trimout on
set tab off
```

Have a look at `help set` if you have the help information installed. And then `select name,address` rather than `select *` if you really only want those two columns.

Comment: @user206168 - the question was about SQL*Plus. Can you expand on what doesn't work?

Comment: What's the point of the `set space 1` and the `set tab off`  ?

Comment: @Coffee - I set tab off so it pads things with spaces instead of tab characters; doesn't matter on-screen but if the output is put in a file then it can have odd effects, if tab widths aren't the same. `set space 1` is redundant though; `space` is [obsolete](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/apc.htm) for start, and it defaults to 1 anyway; but it's the equivalent of `set colsep ' '`. I think I've carried this from a really old environment that defaulted to three spaces between columns, and I just preferred one.

Answer (score 52):

If you mean you want to see them like this:

```
WORKPLACEID NAME       ADDRESS        TELEPHONE
----------- ---------- -------------- ---------
          1 HSBC       Nugegoda Road      43434
          2 HNB Bank   Colombo Road      223423
```

then in SQL Plus you can set the column widths like this (for example):

```
column name format a10
column address format a20
column telephone format 999999999
```

You can also specify the line size and page size if necessary like this:

```
set linesize 100 pagesize 50
```

You do this by typing those commands into SQL Plus before running the query.  Or you can put these commands and the query into a script file e.g. myscript.sql and run that.  For example:

```
column name format a10
column address format a20
column telephone format 999999999

select name, address, telephone
from mytable;
```

Comment: Also we would probably want to `SET PAGESIZE 200` (say) in order to reduce the repetition of the column headings in a big resultset.

Comment: so this should done during the table creation or can you please elobarate more on this

Comment: `lines` and `pages` NEVER worked for me. Using `column` is easy, and fantastic. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can set the line size as per the width of the window and set wrap off using the following command.

```
set linesize 160;
set wrap off;
```

I have used 160 as per my preference you can set it to somewhere between `100 - 200` and setting wrap will not your data and it will display the data properly.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have a dump made with sqlplus and the output is garbled as someone did not set those 3 values before, there's a way out.

Just a couple hours ago DB admin send me that ugly looking output of query executed in sqlplus (I dunno, maybe he hates me...). I had to find a way out: this is an awk script to parse that output to make it at least more readable. It's far not perfect, but I did not have enough time to polish it properly. Anyway, it does the job quite well.

```
awk ' function isDashed(ln){return ln ~ /^---+/};function addLn(){ln2=ln1; ln1=ln0;ln0=$0};function isLoaded(){return l==1||ln2!=""}; function printHeader(){hdr=hnames"\n"hdash;if(hdr!=lastHeader){lastHeader=hdr;print hdr};hnames="";hdash=""};function isHeaderFirstLn(){return isDashed(ln0) && !isDashed(ln1) && !isDashed(ln2) }; function isDataFirstLn(){return isDashed(ln2)&&!isDashed(ln1)&&!isDashed(ln0)}                         BEGIN{_d=1;h=1;hnames="";hdash="";val="";ln2="";ln1="";ln0="";fheadln=""}                                 { addLn();  if(!isLoaded()){next}; l=1;             if(h==1){if(!isDataFirstLn()){if(_d==0){hnames=hnames" "ln1;_d=1;}else{hdash=hdash" "ln1;_d=0}}else{_d=0;h=0;val=ln1;printHeader()}}else{if(!isHeaderFirstLn()){val=val" "ln1}else{print val;val="";_d=1;h=1;hnames=ln1}}   }END{if(val!="")print val}'
```

In case anyone else would like to try improve this script, below are the variables:
hnames -- column names in the header, hdash - dashed below the header, h -- whether I'm currently parsing header (then ==1), val -- the data, _d -
- to swap between hnames and hdash, ln0 - last line read, ln1 - line read previously (it's the one i'm actually working with), ln2 - line read before ln1

Happy parsing!

Oh, almost forgot... I use this to prettify sqlplus output myself:

```
[oracle@ora ~]$ cat prettify_sql 
set lines 256
set trimout on
set tab off
set pagesize 100
set colsep " | "
```

colsep is optional, but it makes output look like sqlite which is easier to parse using scripts.

EDIT: 
A little preview of parsed and non-parsed output

[image: A little preview of parsed and non-parsed output]

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, the stupid linesize ...
Here is what I do in my profile.sql - works only on unixes:

```
echo SET LINES $(tput cols) > $HOME/.login_tmp.sql
@$HOME/.login_tmp.sql
```

if you find an equivalent for tput on Windows, it might work there as well