# Format Oracle query in a shell script

Tags: oracle, bash, sqlplus

I am using sqlplus to connect to an Oracle db from a shell script and the formatting is getting screwed up as below:

```
JOBNAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AVGRUNTIME   SYSTIM AVGRUNTIMEFORMAT     SYSTIMEFORMAT
------------ ------ -------------------- --------------------
FPDPPRL020
015322       211819 01:53:22             21:18:19

FPDPPRL020
014858       211819 01:48:58             21:18:19
~



Expected Output:
---------------
JOBNAME     AVGRUNTIME SYSTIME AVGRUNTIMEFMT SYSTIMEFORMAT
FPDPPRL020  015322     211016   01:53:22     21:10:16
FPDPPRL020  014858     211016   01:48:58     21:10:16
```

Comment: I suggest to fix sqlplus‘ output. This might help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/64620

Comment: You need to set the column width if the default column size is too big. You can also set the overall page width. See for example here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3006583/13189