# Oracle Query return the whole row in a line bash

Tags: bash, shell, sqlplus

I have a Query(Oracle) in Bash like that

```
RETVAL=`sqlplus -S /nolog <<EOF
         connect $ORCL_USR/$ORCL_PWD@$ORCL_TNS;
        SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
        select trim(Colm1) from $MyTable 
    EXIT;
    EOF`
 Result="Result.txt"
 touch $Result
 echo "$RETVAL" >> "$Result"
 cat $Result
```

If i just select a column then the  result is correct , every column( i just have a column) have a line
so.

```
cat Result.txt
 111
 222
 333
```

The problem is when i try to query 2 columns or more
so in Revalt i put:

```
  select trim(Colm1),trim(column2) from $MyTable
```

when i do the Cat $Result.txt the result is:

```
111
Car
222
Hause
333
Dog
```

when i would wish

```
111 Car
222 Hause
333 Dog
```

So every row in a line for the File.

How can achieve it?

Thanks in Advance , Enrique

Comment: What are the column data types in your table? Looks like the output is being wrapped because it is too wide. [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3006431/266304) if you just need to `set linesize`..

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole I thoung the same Column1 -> nummber , Column2-> Varchar 255 , it seems what you said. I ll try it.

Comment: OK, then try adding `LINESIZE 300` to your `SET` command. Why are you using `trim()` for a number - so it's aligned on the left instead of the right? Using `to_char()` would be more intuitive.

Comment: Adding set LINESIZE 300  to the SET command ,didn't solve the problem. i just put the trim() cause i wanted to be sure that was not empty whitespace in the database(even if it was a number) . I know it could seen stupied but i was desesperate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spool command to get the desired output.

```
sqlplus -S /nolog <<EOF
connect $ORCL_USR/$ORCL_PWD@$ORCL_TNS;
spool filepath/Result.txt
SET PAGESIZE 0 FEEDBACK OFF VERIFY OFF HEADING OFF ECHO OFF
select trim(Colm1),trim(column2) from $MyTable 
EXIT;
spool off;
EOF
cat filepath/Result.txt
```

Comment: Hi @Lohit thanks for the idea but with Spool i have exactly the same result.

Comment: @Enrique check the column width of your columns and set linesize accordingly. I think linesize is exceeding the column width.

Comment: Hi @Lohit i did it but it didnt get better . :/