# Select replace empty values with values from different date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server and I have a simple query

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM Rates 
WHERE Date = '2017-06-09 00:00:00'
```

for that date there are no rates, if there are no rates the query should give me results from 2017-06-08 00:00:00
Sample Data:

```
dtmDate int     CurrencyCode    strCurrency dblInRate   dblCCRate 
2012-05-16 00:00:00 12           DZD       0.010545     0.010545 
2012-05-11 00:00:00 12           DZD       0.010511     0.010511
2006-06-26 00:00:00 12           DZD       0.011334     0.011334 
2016-03-30 00:00:00 12           DZD       0.008309     0.008309 
2017-04-26 00:00:00 12           DZD       0.008530     0.008530 
2017-04-28 00:00:00 12           DZD       0.008561     0.008561 
2017-05-03 00:00:00 12           DZD       0.008530     0.008530 
2017-10-13 00:00:00 12           DZD       0.007587     0.007587 
2017-10-19 00:00:00 12           DZD       0.007581     0.007581
```

--and for 2018-06-09 there is nothing no record in the table and I need to replace it with previous date.

So how do I get it to select all rates for all dates when the date is 2017-06-09 then use rates from 2017-06-08, else use the rates for the corresponding date?

Comment: What happen if not data for `2017-06-08` ??

Comment: If there is no Data for Jun-8 it should bring the data from the 7th?

Comment: Would a simple `WHERE Date <= '2017-06-09 00:00:00' ORDER BY Date DESC` do? If not, what are the exact rules for picking a previous day? If there's no data for 2017-06-08 either, what then?

Comment: You can use [date] <= ... order by [date] desc. (I suggest you to use a date literal without any dashes. ie: '20170609' - otherwise you would get erroneous results with some versions and settings).

Comment: Do u have that specific requirement for those two dates or you will need to select data from date-1

Comment: use Exists to testi if ther is date data

Comment: No no, I need to select all rates, data, from all days, but for the 9.6.2017 there are no rates(data) so in such case the query should replace it with data from previous day, but also give me results from 5.6, 6.6, 10.6 11.6 etc etc.

Comment: Could you add some sample data and expected result for each day?  Also, if you're querying for each day separately, then you already should have the data for the 8th if there is no data on the 9th.  Simply post it again in the display.  No need to query the data over and over.

Comment: can you detailed exmaple

Comment: Here is the sample:
dtmDate intCurrencyCode strCurrency dblInRate dblCCRate
2012-05-16 00:00:00 12 DZD 0.010545 0.010545
2012-05-11 00:00:00 12 DZD 0.010511 0.010511
2006-06-26 00:00:00 12 DZD 0.011334 0.011334
2016-03-30 00:00:00 12 DZD 0.008309 0.008309
2017-04-26 00:00:00 12 DZD 0.008530 0.008530
2017-04-28 00:00:00 12 DZD 0.008561 0.008561
2017-05-03 00:00:00 12 DZD 0.008530 0.008530
2017-10-13 00:00:00 12 DZD 0.007587 0.007587
2017-10-19 00:00:00 12 DZD 0.007581 0.007581

and for 2018-06-09 there is nothing no record in the table and I need to replace it with previous date.

Comment: If you are selecting data from All dates  , you will still only get top 10 rows as you need. This doesn't make any sense

Comment: David Include the data and expected output on the question not at the comments You can format your data here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006431/how-to-display-table-data-more-clearly-in-oracle-sqlplus

Comment: If you have 0 rates from day 09, 7 rates from day 08 and 5 rates from day 07 do you get rates from 08 and 07 ? In this case got all 7 from day 08 and random 3 from day 07 ? or just the 7 from day  08?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT TOP 10 r.* 
FROM (SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES r.*
      FROM Rates r
      WHERE Date <= '2017-06-09'
      ORDER BY Date DESC
     ) r;
```

The `TOP (1) WITH TIES` returns all records with the same date (assuming there is no time component, which is consistent with your sample data and question).  The `WHERE` says the date is no later than 2017-06-09.  The `ORDER BY` says that it is the most recent date on or before the specified date.

The outer `TOP (10)` chooses 10 of these arbitrarily, as does your query.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks, but it is not this what I need. I need all the data from this table  and I know there are no data for this one correct date so I need to select * from rates when date is 9.6.2018 then use rates from date 8.6.2017

Comment: @DavidBelovezcik . . . That is what this query does.

Comment: This is clever solution, as I understand it inner selection will return all rates for single day (`top 1 with ties`) and the order guarantees you will get the newest available before or for given date.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM Rates 
WHERE Date <= '2017-06-09 00:00:00'
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can cast your specific column to 'date' and compare it with the filter. just like that:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM Rates 
WHERE cast(Date as date)= '2017-06-09'
```