# I am not able to understand why I am getting this type of an output in SQLPlus. If someone could help me out with this it would be great

Tags: sqlplus, oracle19c

[This is the output of the PLAYERS Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEGAz.png)

The column headings should be horizontally in a single row, followed by a dotted line in the next row and then the corresponding entries under each column heading.
Instead I am getting an output as being shown in the image.

Comment: Don't include images of text. Copy-paste the text into the question and format it using markdown.

Comment: Also [How to display table data more clearly in oracle sqlplus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3006431/266304). You might also want to look the SQLcl client.

Comment: @MT0 I'll make sure to take care of the same next time. Thank you for helping out.

Comment: @AlexPoole It did get resolved by following the solution given in the provided link. Thanks a lot